# Android разработка, URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks

Tags: java, android, build, apk

В общем, для многих, скорее всего, этот вопрос будет глупым, но для меня сейчас он является проблемой. Написал я кот, т.е. код. В эмуляторе он работает. После создал ключ, чтобы подписать Apk. После создал apk файл. Но на смартфоне не работает, просто останавливается сразу приложение. Начал копаться, нажал Build - >Analyze APK, там открыл Android Manifest. И вот там горит красным строка xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android". Хотя в Manifest файле проекта такого нет. Но в APK Manifeste ошибка "URI is not registered ...". Прошу помочь тех, у кого есть время и терпение! Заранее благодарю.
[image: Картинка ошибки]

Доп информация. Ипользую JSONobject-ы для передачи инфы между фрагментами. Fragments наследую от android.app.Fragment. Основная Activity - Navigation Drawer Activity.

Comment: Нужно подключить телефон к компьютеру, в Android Studio открыть нижнюю вкладку Android Monitor, выбрать своё устройство из выпадающего списка, запустить на нём приложение и смотреть что пишется в лог когда приложение падает.
После этого стек трейс ошибки приложите к своему вопросу

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь) Даже не подумал о логах. Было во Fragment-ах в методе onAttach ошибки. Надо было просто public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    } а AndroidStudio добавляло if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }. Еще нужно было в Activity добавить код, чтобы у пользователя спрашивалось разрешение на запись

Comment: А в Analyze Apk так же горит строчка красным цветом и дает ошибку URI is not registered... Но видимо это не критично) Спасибо за помощь еще раз!